# Convert std::string to QString

Tags: c++, string, qt, utf-8, qstring

I've got an `std::string content` that I know contains UTF-8 data. I want to convert it to a [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html). How do I do that, avoiding the from-ASCII conversion in Qt?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There's a `QString` function called [`fromUtf8`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromUtf8) that takes a `const char*`:

```
QString str = QString::fromUtf8(content.c_str());
```

Comment: More efficient: `QString::fromUtf8( content.data(), content.size() )`

Comment: In the C++ standard there is no guarantee, that `std::string` is encoded in UTF8 (actually the encoding is unspecified), so this answer is not entirely correct. At least you should check the encoding by an assertion.

Answer (score 135):

`QString::fromStdString(content)` is better since it is more robust. Also note, that if `std::string` is encoded in UTF-8, then it should give exactly the same result as `QString::fromUtf8(content.data(), int(content.size()))`.

Comment: Only in Qt5. In Qt4 it uses QString::fromAscii.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However your last statement is not necessarily true. In the C++ standard there is no guarantee, that `std::string` is encoded in UTF8 (actually the encoding is unspecified), so `QString::fromUtf8(content.data(), int(content.size()))` may give different (and also incorrect) results than `QString::fromStdString(content)`.

Answer (score 15):

Since **Qt5** fromStdString internally uses fromUtf8, so you can use both:

```
inline QString QString::fromStdString(const std::string& s) 
{
return fromUtf8(s.data(), int(s.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Usually, the best way of doing the conversion is using the method [fromUtf8](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromUtf8), but the problem is when you have strings locale-dependent.

In these cases, it's preferable to use [fromLocal8Bit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#fromLocal8Bit). Example:

```
std::string str = "ëxample";
QString qs = QString::fromLocal8Bit(str.c_str());
```