# Which function pair in QString to use for converting to/from std::string?

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm working on a project that we want to use Unicode and could end up in countries like Japan, etc...  We want to use std::string for the underlying type that holds string data in the data layer (see [Qt, MSVC, and /Zc:wchar_t- == I want to blow up the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521252/qt-msvc-and-zcwchar-t-i-want-to-blow-up-the-world) as to why).  The problem is that I'm not completely sure which function pair (to/from) to use for this and be sure we're 100% compatible with anything the user might enter in the Qt layer.

A look at to/fromStdString indicates that I'd have to use setCodecForCStrings.  The documentation for that function though indicates that I wouldn't want to do this for things like Japanese.  This is the set that I'd LIKE to use though.  Does someone know enough to explain how I'd set this up if it's possible?

The other option that looks like I could be pretty sure of it working is the to/fromUTF8 functions.  Those would require a two step approach though so I'd prefer the other if possible.

Is there anything I've missed?

Comment: You would be actually using std:: **w** string, I hope!

Comment: Come on guys!  At least read the question before responding or please just don't bother!  The whole wstring thing has been discussed already and I provided a direct link for anyone who's worried about it.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you were re-posting a previous question. Have you tried compiling those libraries and run into problems making a simple test application? Is it possible for you to just use std::basic_string with the character type you want and avoid the library compiling problem altogether? What have you actually tried so far I guess ...

Comment: part of the question is answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338067/convert-stdstring-to-qstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is a bit disconcerting here (on `QString`). However, the docs on `QTextCodec` don't seem to note any problems. It does however return QByteArray instead of a std::string. You can of course easily convert `QByteArray` to a `std::string`.  But if you look at the source for `QString` you'll see that `toStdString` does exactly that:

```
inline std::string QString::toStdString() const
{ const QByteArray asc = toAscii(); return std::string(asc.constData(), asc.length()); }
```

`toAscii` in turn will use whatever codec has been set with `QTextCodec::setCodecForCString`.

Their warning about the Japanese codec is likely valid, however, if your OS is using the Japanese codec you likely won't have a problem. I'm not entirely sure here.

But you can avoid that problem. Simply set your codec as UTF-8  and then toStdString should convert everything into UTF-8. In fact I'm going to do that with my code right now. :)

Comment: Thanks for reading the question!!  Setting the codec to UTF-8 is probably what I want.