# How to use standard C++ code with Qt code in the same program?

Tags: c++, qt

```
string m ="kosala";
ui->label_5->setText(m);
```

This gives me :

> string is undeclared identifier

I want to use string data type as in here without QString type. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You possibly forgot

```
#include<string>
```

And you should call the type `std::string`.

```
std::string m ="kosala";
```

Comment: drew , i did like that also but it gives like this error ....   error: C2664: 'QLabel::setText' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::string' to 'const QString &'
Reason: cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'const QString'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: @KosalaJayakody http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338067  I believe this answered your original question?  If you have a new question, I recommend [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).